# Corrupt axes and floor lines in Blender 2.83.0 on Mac OS

Tags: osx

I'm experiencing strange graphical corruption in a file, where the axes lines and grid have strange lines. (see attached picture below)

I have only one project file with this problem, it seems that the axis lines have "corrupt" lines when moving around the scene in all of the viewport tabs. The problem started after adding an empty for the camera to track, the screen went grey, so I refocused on an object in my scene to find it again, then these lines showed up.

Has anyone else experienced this, and/or is there a way to resolve it? Does anyone have any suggestions to troubleshoot it?

So far I have tried:

- removing the empty object
- giving the file to a friend (they deleted the empty and it went away)
- trying a new file (did not have the same issue)
- restarting blender

Details of system:

- iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Mid 2015), AMD Radeon R9 M290 2 GB
- Version: Mac OS 10.14.6
- Blender 2.83.0

Thank you.

[image: Blender corrupt axes and floor]